# zsh ${var##$pat} parameter expansion with pattern var containing globs

Tags: zsh, glob, parameter-expansion

It seems `zsh` doesn't honor globs inside *variable* patterns, in `${var##$pat}` parameter expansions:

```
$ zsh -c 'pat=/*; var=/etc/; echo "$var $pat"; echo "${var##$pat}"'
/etc/ /*
/etc/
# sh result: empty
```

However, if `$pat` does not contain `*`, zsh and sh behave similarly:

```
$ zsh -c 'pat=/; var=/etc/; echo "$var $pat"; echo "${var##$pat}"'
/etc/ /
etc/
# sh result: same
```

`zsh --emulate sh` gives, of course, sh-compatible results. But if I want to stay in zsh emulation, is there any `setopt` option that changes this behavior? I've looked (briefly) in the docs and I can't really find the reason for this difference.

Comment: In zsh, a simple `echo $pat` would also not expand the pattern, so it would be odd if such an expansion occurs by default in the context you present here. The zsh way to activate wildcards in a variable is, i.e., `echo $~pat`.

Comment: My scenario is that I'm trying to write a portable script (which I did not mention in the question).

Comment: _portable_ in which way? Accross different zsh versions? Note that zsh had quite some changes during its history.

Comment: Portable on present-day machines

Comment: Given that most languages (in particular bash and zsh) are available on virtually every platform i am aware of, you could stick with one of those, and just not assume that you will have the most recent version available. If you really are paranoic about portability (for instance, it should run on a machine where you don't have the permission to install anything), you could develop in in POSIX shell and simply ignore zsh completely; `sh` should really be available everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, variable contents will only be treated as a pattern if you
ask for that, with a `${~spec}` expansion or the (very broad and therefore slightly dangerous) GLOB_SUBST option:

```
pat=/*t
var=/etc/
print "${var##$pat}"
#=> /etc/
print "${var##$~pat}"
#=> c/
setopt glob_subst
print "${var##$pat}"
#=> c/
```

This is described in the `zshexpn` man page, in the section for string substitution expansion `${name/pattern/repl}`.

Comment: I see; does `setopt GLOB_SUBST` also make `$pat` glob filenames (in `${var##$pat}`)?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't seem so from simple tests, but there is ambiguity to contend with

Comment: I cannot find an explicit manual reference about how that works, but the `Rules` section in the `zshexpn` man page indicates that filename expansion comes later than other expansions, so a variable will be treated as a string pattern in contexts that require a string pattern, and then later as a glob pattern in contexts that allow that. So for example each of the tildes in `v=/etc/*; p=/*c; print ${~v##$~p}` will have a different effect. NB: the Rules section literally has a (joke) warning about brain damage from reading them, so be careful :-).